# Creating a browser plugin like Flash

Tags: .net, browser-plugin

I would like to create a browser plugin which works LIKE flash, with embedded content from my application on the page.

How would I go about doing this? Is it doable with .net applications?

Thanks for the help.

EDIT: To clarify, I have no intention of making something EXACTLY like flash, or remotely similar. I merely wish to be able to embed my application in-browser, and let the user pass parameters or whatever.

Comment: Silverlight did it, so I assume it's doable with .Net.. Also, be aware that you must code your application for two different browsers, Internet Explorer, and everything else(which falls under some kinda netscape API)

Comment: Of course, I just need some sort of reference manual or API to be able to start.

Comment: Your comments make your question less clear. Silverlight is the answer but not for you... so clarify your question...

Answer (score 7):

For FF/Chrome etc you need [NPAPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NPAPI). Can't imagine doing it in .Net

For IE it's just a COM object. Theoretically you could do it in .Net

If you are not accessing any local resources (special hardware etc) on the browsers computer then you might as well just use Silverlight. [Lot of samples of what Silverlight can do](http://silverlight.net/community/samples/silverlight-samples/)

Answer (score 3):

Flash and Silverlight are both decent platforms for writing your own custom apps which run in the browser and display custom content.  If you're familiar with .NET, then writing a Silverlight app should be pretty straightforward.

Silverlight is probably what you are looking for since it allows you to write self contained .NET apps which run inside the browser.  You can pass parameters to it, or allow it to make any sort of WCF call(REST/SOAP/XML-RPC/etc) or call any javascript function on your page.

Comment: I would prefer to not use Silverlight, and in this case Flash is far from sufficient.

Comment: What is wrong with Silverlight?  This is precisely the purpose it was designed for.

Comment: @Cyclone: But Silverlight does exactly what you ask. Maybe you should clarify your original question?

Comment: I have an EXISTING application which I would like to embed in-browser, with a user passing parameters to it.

Comment: @Cyclone: and what exactly about your application makes it non-compatible with Silverlight? Interop?

Comment: I believe you may want to look at the god-forsaken API that is ActiveX for that.. but it's not nearly so trivial as you would think.

Comment: It seems that the consensus is to use Silverlight. Assuming your program doesn't do any crazy interop/pinvoke magic, it should be a simple case of swapping your presentation code to use WPF and recompile for Silverlight.  Otherwise, you're going to have to learn the ActiveX/NPAPI routes and try and get your app to behave properly in that environment.

Comment: How can I start using Silverlight?

Comment: Visual Studio Web Express 2010 should let you build Silverlight apps.

Answer (score 2):

Be aware that if you actually want more than a handful of people to be able
to use your plug-in you'll need to deal with versions for all sorts of operating
systems and platforms. If it's just for something on a local office intranet
you might be ok, but otherwise you'll end up needing to write Mac, Windows, Windows 64bit, Linux, Linux 64bit, iPhone, Android, etc. versions. You'll
then need to take care of really complex security issues and weird bugs
that people have all the time. It's not a small undertaking.

Do you want to do something that you can't already do just by using one of the existing plugins like Flash or Java?

Comment: Or Silverlight since Cyclone wants to use .NET

Comment: Windows is the only system my plugin would apply to.

Comment: @Cyclone - why only Windows? Just asking.

Comment: @Moshe why not? If he's working in .NET, it's the default option unless there's a strong reason to bother with mono.

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking into this recently - you clearly have to do a lot of per-platform and per-browser work (I haven't found a magical one size fits all solution).

My application was 3d rendering, so this series was pretty useful (obviously substituting the Irrlicht stuff for your own code/library):

http://copperbit.com/?p=20

There is also a follow up article on FireFox...

Comment: That page doesn't seem to exist any more. Anyone got another link to it?

Comment: Here's the best I could do - looks like a scrape without images or source.  Sorry - http://tinyurl.com/48ez9wj